# Random row selection within a subset of a database which has been filtered by a value

Tags: mysql

I have a database called 'images' at the moment I am randomly selecting 2 rows based on RAND() and ORDER.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,2";
$result = @mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
     $images[] = (object) $row;
}
```

This is working fine. However, instead I would like to randomly select one row (randomrow1) and then create a subset of the images database filter by score > (randomrow1$score - 100) & score < (randomrow1$score + 100). Then randomly select another row from the subset without it being identical to randomrow1.

I then need to resulting rows to work in the following code:

```
        <td valign="top" class="image"><a href="rate.php?winner=<?=$images[0]->image_id?>&loser=<?=$images[1]->image_id?>"><img src="images/<?=$image1->filename?>" /></a></td>
        <td valign="top" class="image"><a href="rate.php?winner=<?=$images[1]->image_id?>&loser=<?=$images[0]->image_id?>"><img src="images/<?=$image2->filename?>" /></a></td>
```

Comment: Can you share a little more of the schema with us about images? Is there an id property?

Comment: filename, score, wins, losses, image_id - there are 1000 rows in the images database

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not suppress errors when calling methods with the `@` operator. If something goes wrong you want to know about it and will need to take corrective action, display a useful message for the user, log the problem, or all that and more. It also makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated if you ignore errors that are trying to point out serious problems.

Comment: Another advice, always initialize variables outside the loop before using them in the loop. Think of worst scenarios. If your `images` table is empty, you'll end up with an Undefined `$images` variable in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, begin by changing your original code to only get one answer.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = @mysql_query($query);
$image = (object) mysql_fetch_object($result)
```

Then you need to extract the score which would be done by getting the score of the only image object so for example

```
$score1 = $image["score"]
$id1 = $image["id"]
```

Then you would have to query again:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM images WHERE score < #{$score1} + 100 AND score > #{$score1} - 100 AND id != #{$id1} ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"
$result = @mysql_query($query)
$image2 = (object) mysql_fetch_object($result)
```

My syntax may be a little rusty but this general answer should work for you.

Comment: Thanks Josh would that save 2 items in $image or will the 2nd query overwrite the first?

Comment: It would have overwritten, that was an oversight. Should be fixed now.

Comment: The main idea in the answer is valid, if you get the syntax working. However mind that there is necessary another criteria in the second query in order to follow the requirements: **...without it being identical to randomrow1**

Comment: Thanks for the help guys... your answer leads to a further issue further down the code. I will edit the initial question

Comment: @JoshKopen I have edited the original question and hoping you would be able to help

Comment: @DenJJ Sorry I don't know much about the second half of the question, good luck

Comment: Thanks Josh - appreciate your help